# Fast way to find the maximum of all elements before i in a list in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array, X, which I want to make monotonic. Specifically, I want to do

```
y = x.copy()    
for i in range(1, len(x)):
    y[i] = np.max(x[:i])
```

This is extremely slow for large arrays, but it feels like there should be a more efficient way of doing this. How can this operation be sped up?

Comment: how do you find the max number from an empty list x[:0], I think it generates an error

Comment: `np.maximum.accumulate(x)`?

Comment: The above code does not work. Did you mean `x[:i + 1]` instead of `x[:i]` inside `np.max()`? Or did you meant to start the range from `1`? Or else?

Comment: Yes you're right it should start from 1. I'll edit the question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The OP implementation is very inefficient because it does not use the information acquired on the previous iteration, resulting in `O(n²)` complexity.

```py
def max_acc_OP(arr):
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        result[i] = np.max(arr[:i + 1])
    return result
```

Note that I *fixed* the OP code (which was otherwise throwing a `ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity`)  by allowing to get the largest value among those up to position `i` included.

It is easy to adapt that so that values at position `i` are excluded, but it leaves the first value of the result undefined, and it would never use the last value of the input. The first value of the result can be taken to be equal to the first value of the input, e.g.:

```py
def max_acc2_OP(arr):
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    result[0] = arr[0]  # uses first value of input
    for i in range(1, len(arr) + 1):
        result[i] = np.max(arr[:i])
    return result
```

It is equally easy to have similar adaptations for the code below, and I do not think it is particularly relevant to cover both cases of the value at position `i` included and excluded. Henceforth, only the "included" case is covered.

Back to the efficiency of the solotion,  if you keep track of the current maximum and use that to fill your output array instead of re-computing the maximum for all value up to `i` at each iteration, you can easily get to `O(n)` complexity:

```py
def max_acc(arr):
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    curr_max = arr[0]
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):
        if x > curr_max:
            curr_max = x
        result[i] = curr_max
    return result
```

However, this is still relatively slow because of the explicit looping.
Luckily, one can either rewrite this in vectorized form combining [`np.fmax()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fmax.html#numpy.fmax) (or [`np.maximum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html#numpy-maximum) -- depending on how you need NaNs to be handled) and [`np.ufunc.accumulate()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html#numpy-ufunc-accumulate):

```py
np.fmax.accumulate()

# or

np.maximum.accumulate()
```

or, accelerating the solution above with Numba:

```py
max_acc_nb = nb.njit(max_acc)
```

---

Some timings on relatively large inputs are provided below:

```py
n = 10000
arr = np.random.randint(0, n, n)
%timeit -n 4 -r 4 max_acc_OP(arr)
# 97.5 ms ± 14.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
%timeit -n 4 -r 4 np.fmax.accumulate(arr)
# 112 µs ± 134 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
%timeit -n 4 -r 4 np.maximum.accumulate(arr)
# 88.4 µs ± 107 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
%timeit -n 4 -r 4 max_acc(arr)
# 2.32 ms ± 146 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
%timeit -n 4 -r 4 max_acc_nb(arr)
# 9.11 µs ± 3.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
```

indicating that `max_acc()` is already much faster than `max_acc_OP()`, but `np.maximum.accumulate()` / `np.fmax.accumulate()` is even faster, and `max_acc_nb()` comes out as the fastest. As always, it is important to take these kind of numbers with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work faster to just keep track of the maximum rather than calculating it each time for each sub-array

```
y = x.copy()    
_max = y[0]
for i in range(1, len(x)):
    y[i] = _max
    _max = max(x[i], _max)
```

Comment: This code would produce wrong results, if you have `x = [0, 1]`, it will produce `y = [0, 0]` instead of `y = [0, 1]`. Perhaps you should first compute the temporary max and then eventually assign it to `y[i]`?

Comment: I got that the task is to find the maximum among the values before the i-th? In this case y = [0, 0] is the right result for x = [0, 1].

Comment: Sorry, my bad. There is some divergence on what OP code does (throws an error), and what it asks for in words.

Comment: Anyway thanks to you I've just spotted a mistake in my code:) It changes y[i] before it actually compares it to the maximum. So y[i] value needs to be saved somewhere before it's changed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension for it. but you need to start your loop from 1 not from 0. either you can use like that if you want loop from 0.

```
y=[np.max(x[:i+1]) for i in range(len(x))]
```

or like that

```
y=[np.max(x[:i]) for i in range(1,len(x)+1)]
```

Comment: This solves the issue of computing `np.max()` on an empty array, but it would not speed up the computation.

Comment: @norok2 yeah maybe you are right but most of the time list comprehension is faster than the loop.

Comment: I am not sure what are you comparing exactly. List comprehension are typically within a few percent of the equivalent code using `list.append()`. OP's code is producing a NumPy array though, so I am not sure it is fair / useful to produce a `list` instead.

Comment: @norok2 I did not understand. can you suggest me your solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73960372/5218354